# Inner rounded shadows inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which looks something like this:

```css
.box{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 border: solid 0.01rem #2e2e2e;
 border-radius: 3px;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"/>
```

And I'm trying to achieve this effect. How can I make this box look with such shadows from the inside of the div?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient())
- [blur filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/blur())
- [absolute positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)
- [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)
- [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 10%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, red, #c10606);
  position: relative;
}

.box:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 10%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, #c10606);
  border-radius: 12%;
  filter: blur(1px);  /* optional for a softer effect */
}

/* optional layout and styling for box contents */
.box {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: arial;
  color: #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.box * {
  position: relative;  /* puts interior content over the pseudo-element */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>Interior content</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

## [CSS `box-shadow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow)

I think the answer posted by @isherwood works as the best one for your use-case. But, there *is* a way to make the shadow show on the inside of the element by setting the last parameter of `box-shadow` as `inset`.
There are a few catches for this solution though. A few things which I could not achieve:

1. I am unable to implement linear gradient to the shadow.
2. I am unable to give a `border-radius` to the inner boundary of the shadow.

---

```css
div.box {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, hsl(26, 68%, 26%), hsl(26, 68%, 45%));
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 12px hsl(26, 68%, 35%) inset;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

Reference: [How to create an inner shadow using CSS](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-create-an-inner-shadow-using-css)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I edited your code. Here is [the demo](https://codepen.io/raajkhan/pen/XWzRBqg).

Basically, I added one more div and added some style. Hope it will give you an idea.

Also, I added a snippet down below:-

```css
.box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid 0.01rem #2e2e2e;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.inner-div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 78px;
  height: 78px;
  background: #ee1717;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"/>
<div class="inner-div"></div>
<div>
```

Comment: The background gradient is a critical aspect of this effect.